# Spellcheck enabled in Hybrid Mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am building a mobile application that uses the following technologies

- HTML5 / CSS3 / JavaScript
- jQuery and jQuery Mobile
- Cordova

And I want to **enable** the spelling autocorrect that autmoatically fixes obvious spelling mistakes

such as fixing Teh *automatically* into The

What kind of a plugin will do the job?  Or what should I add in my code?

The HTML5 of my mobile application

```
<textarea name="textarea-1" id="desiredpart" spellcheck="true" autocorrect="on" ></textarea>
```

And then in my JavaScript

```
$( document ).ready(function( ) {
    $desiredpart = $("#desiredpart"); 
    $desiredpart.attr("spellcheck","on").attr("autocorrect","on");
});
```

And my JavaScript is imported **after** the jQuery mobile file loads.
I read that jQuery mobile disables autocorrect and spellcheck.  Should I modify the jQuery mobile source code?

Comment: `autmoatically`, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a snippet of the code from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.js
[image: Jquery mobile autocorrect feature]
You can playaround these lines and see the results in various devices.

I would suggest you stick to the HTML attribute option as it has lower overhead on the DOM.

Comment: Just give it a try.We can come up with some solution based on the results you get.

Comment: No it still did not enable it.  Thanks for your work :)

Comment: Can you check whether removing references of both Jquery mobile and Jquery js from the HTML enables the autocorrect and spellcheck feature in device?